# In Windows phone, in a added c# class dont work dispatcher

Tags: windows-phone-8, dispatcher

i tried to use this.Dispatcher in a added class in Windows Phone i get the error " does not contain a defenition for Dispatcher...".
How can i solve this Problem?
Thanks!

Comment: an example of your code will help us, help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this  snippet :

```
SynchronizationContext cont = SynchronizationContext.Current;
cont.Post((foo) => {}, null );
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a other Solution!!
If u add :PhoneApplicationPage to ur class. , in my Exampel: public class savelist: PhoneApplicationPage, than will Dispatcher work

Comment: That is not a particularly good thing to do; there is no need to derive from `PhoneApplicationPage` unless you really are building a custom Page.

Answer (score 0):

For Silverlight-based apps, you can use `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` from any context.